# Jquery resize container tables of the page

Tags: jquery, css, html-table

I have an HTML page that has many nested tables, for example table for header and table for content and another for footer, and each table has some child tables

the problems is that I don't have access to tables to give them IDs or Classes, I can only attach JavaScript or CSS file to the page (because it's based on oracle portal) the page is full width, all tables take 100% width,

I want to re-size the tables ( the parents only) to be 1020px width, without touching those tables on with jQuery or CSS.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('body > table')' should give you the immediate table children

Comment: this worked fine but it aligned all the tables to the left, how can I align them center ?

Comment: add this CSS: `width:1020px; margin:0 auto`

Comment: I added this   $('body > table').width(1030);
$('body > table').css('margin','0 auto'); but it is working fine only on firefox not for internet explorer

Comment: Sorry just saw this after seeing your other question. Have replied over there. It should work.